# Can I use query parameters as variables in stylus?

Tags: css, node.js, stylus

I would really like to be able to say

```
a {
    color: $COLOR;
}
```

and request it with `/styles.css?COLOR=red`. Is there any way I can do this? I'll also accept `$_GET['COLOR']` or something similar.

If there is no direct support for this (and I couldn't find any), is there any way I can utilize the `compile` function to accomplish this?

Comment: +1 for interesting question.

Comment: How are you using `stylus` for requests of `/styles.css` currently? Are you just using the provided [middleware](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/middleware.html)?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Yep. I'm using express, so `app.use(stylus.middleware({...}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to code this  as a 2-step process:

1. Use regular express code with a simple templating language like ejs or underscore templates to interpolate the color value into the stylus file.
2. Then render the stylus file and respond with the CSS